# Is Spring upgrading their JS validation framework or is JQuery a better choice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, dojo

We started a large project in 2009 and chose Dojo (1.4 at the time) because of Spring's support for Dojo and their nice Spring validation code. Unfortunately Dojo is now on 1.9.3 and from everything I've read it looks like Spring/Dojo development pretty much stopped right about the time we settled on it.

Is Spring ever going to move forward and update their Dojo-based validation code to the newer versions, or have we walked into an evolutionary dead end here?

It looks like JQuery has a very well-done and full-featured validation plugin, unfortunately this would require a complete rewrite of our code.    However, if Spring will never support future versions of Dojo, we will wind up rewriting our code at some point anyway.

Would rewriting using JQuery be a better option than rewriting using Dojo 1.9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to rewrite, it's better to do it in jQuery: you will find more help online, more developers to maintain the code.

Also according to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.RC1/reference/pdf/spring-webflow-reference.pdf), spring-dojo is being deprecated in spring webflow 2.4, so you will no longer have support for it in the near future:

> Deprecations This release deprecates Spring.js. The deprecation
>   includes the entire spring-js-resources module including Spring.js and
>   Spring-Dojo.js and the bundled Dojo and CSS Framework. Also deprecated
>   is the SpringJavascriptAjaxHandler from the spring-js module. The rest
>   of spring-js, e.g. AjaxHandler, AjaxTilesView, will be folded into
>   spring-webflow in a future release

Comment: Ouch.  Deprecation kind of makes the decision for us.   Thanks for pointing that out.